# Display X Amount of Wordpress Posts Based On Title Length

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have a navigation drop-down at the top of a theme I have developed. Basically in the navigation there are 2 columns and one of them displaying retrieved post titles (which is easy).

I however would like to display post titles and a link to the specific post, but because the space is limited to about 40 characters and each link separated by a pipe, I need to work out how to show a certain amount of post titles to fit within my character limit.

Basically if a post heading takes up 40 characters then I don't want to display any other headings, basically I need to get the length of all post titles combined and work out which ones can be displayed to fit within the character limit constraints.

**Example of what I mean** in-case you can't yet understand what I am trying to do.

> **COMMUNITY**         Post heading | Another post heading

I have the following code which does the pulling of posts and then counts the total number of characters in the titles. I can't get it to output the links separated by pipes with the character constraint applied.

```
/* Fetches all post data from the Wordpress DB */
$fetched_posts = array(

    'community'     => get_posts('numberposts=3&tag=community'),
    'communication' => get_posts('numberposts=3&tag=communication'),
    'energy'        => get_posts('numberposts=3&tag=energy'),
    'health'        => get_posts('numberposts=3&tag=health'),
    'prosperity'    => get_posts('numberposts=3&tag=prosperity'),
    'simplicity'    => get_posts('numberposts=3&tag=simplicity'),
    'materials'     => get_posts('numberposts=3&tag=materials'),
    'mobility'      => get_posts('numberposts=3&tag=mobility'),
    'aesthetic'     => get_posts('numberposts=3&tag=aesthetic')
);

// Convert all array entries into variables
extract($fetched_posts);

 /**
 * Show menu items will output items from a particular tagged category
 * but only as many that will fit in the navigation menu space.
 * 
 * @param mixed $object
 * @param mixed $maximum
 */
 function show_menu_items($object, $maximum = 40) {

     // Number of elements in the array
     $total   = 0;

     // Total number of characters we've counted
     $counted = 0;

     // Store all of the titles for this particular object
     foreach ($object as $object) {
        $post_titles[] = $object->post_title;   
     }

     // Store the total number of elements in the array
     $total = count($post_titles);

     // For every post title found count the characters
    foreach ($post_titles as $post_title) {
        if (strlen($post_title) )
        $counted = $counted + strlen($post_title);
    }

    echo $counted;

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I worked out the solution. It wasn't easy, but eventually worked out how to limit the number of posts based on character constraints. No doubt others will find this answer helpful, here's the code:

```
<?php

/* Fetches all post data from the Wordpress DB */
$fetched_posts = array(

    'community'     => get_posts('numberposts=3&tag=community'),
    'communication' => get_posts('numberposts=3&tag=communication'),
    'energy'        => get_posts('numberposts=3&tag=energy'),
    'health'        => get_posts('numberposts=3&tag=health'),
    'prosperity'    => get_posts('numberposts=3&tag=prosperity'),
    'simplicity'    => get_posts('numberposts=3&tag=simplicity'),
    'materials'     => get_posts('numberposts=3&tag=materials'),
    'mobility'      => get_posts('numberposts=3&tag=mobility'),
    'aesthetic'     => get_posts('numberposts=3&tag=aesthetic')
);

// Convert all array entries into variables
extract($fetched_posts);

 /**
 * Show menu items will output items from a particular tagged category
 * but only as many that will fit in the navigation menu space.
 * 
 * @param mixed $object
 * @param mixed $maximum
 */
 function show_menu_items($object, $maximum = 70) {

     // Number of elements in the array
     $total   = 0;

     // Total number of characters we've counted
     $counted = 0;

     // The counter for number of iterations
     $counter = 0;

     // Store all of the titles for this particular object
     foreach ($object as $object) {
        $post_titles[] = $object->post_title; 
     }

     // Store the total number of elements in the array
     $total = count($post_titles);

     // If we actually have page nav items
     if ($total != 0) { 

         // For every post title found count the characters
        foreach ($post_titles as $post_title) {

            // Count characters and keep counting for every title
            $counted = $counted + strlen($post_title);

             // Increment the counterizzle
            $counter++;

            // If the length is less than or equal to our maximum
            if ($counted != $maximum) {

                // Display the links
                echo '<a href="#'.url_title($post_title, 'dash', TRUE).'">'.$post_title.'</a>';

                if ($counter != $total) {
                    echo ' | ';
                }

            }

        }

    } else {
        echo 'No for this subject...';
    }


 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it with `strlen()`. Just keep looping over your headings and append the next heading as long as it is still less than 40.

The problem is the boundary cases. For example when a heading is 38 characters long. It is less than 40, so the logic above would add `| Next Heading` which would put it well over 40 characters. To resolve this, you either need to look ahead at the next heading to see if it fits, or add some kind of shortening to you headings, i.e. `Heading | Ne...ng`

Comment: I kind of see what you mean Jason. Have you got any example code you can provide me to help me out? I've been banging my head against this for a while now. Truncating isn't really an option, I just want to display any amount of headlines that will fit provided the total of characters for all post headings combined never goes over the maximum value.